# How can I get all the information from the GitHub API

Tags: javascript, github-api

I have one question. I'm making GET request with vanilla JavaScript on a public GitHub API, and I'm getting a response, but not the full information on a single user. How can I get all the information like Twitter username or Twitter account link?

Only response I'm getting on each user:
[image: Only response I'm getting on each user:]

Here's my code just in case:

```
function loadUsers() {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  const URL = 'https://api.github.com/users';

  xhr.open('GET', URL, true);

  xhr.onload = function() {
    if(this.status == 200) {
      let users = this.responseText;
      console.log(users);
    }
  }
  xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: [Documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/users). Looks like GH suggests the `octokit` library.

Comment: BTW, I'd suggest to use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) instead of the old, more complicated `XMLHttpRequest`. If you need to support IE - use [Github fetch polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch)

Comment: Yea, I know it's old way but for now i prefered to use XMLHttpRequest. Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each user, you receive a url for more details api. In your example, the first user has

```json
{
  ...
  "url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo",
  ...
},
```

Or just follow the schema `https://api.github.com/users/{username}`
If you call this url ([try](https://api.github.com/users/mojombo)), you will get the twitter account and more.

```js
{
  "login": "mojombo",
  "id": 1,
  "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjE=",
  "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1?v=4",
  "gravatar_id": "",
  "url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo",
  "html_url": "https://github.com/mojombo",
  "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/followers",
  "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/following{/other_user}",
  "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/gists{/gist_id}",
  "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
  "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/subscriptions",
  "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/orgs",
  "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/repos",
  "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/events{/privacy}",
  "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/received_events",
  "type": "User",
  "site_admin": false,
  "name": "Tom Preston-Werner",
  "company": "@chatterbugapp, @redwoodjs, @preston-werner-ventures ",
  "blog": "http://tom.preston-werner.com",
  "location": "San Francisco",
  "email": null,
  "hireable": null,
  "bio": null,
  "twitter_username": "mojombo",
  "public_repos": 62,
  "public_gists": 62,
  "followers": 22447,
  "following": 11,
  "created_at": "2007-10-20T05:24:19Z",
  "updated_at": "2021-03-18T22:50:53Z"
}
```